# Trying to compare two outputs in an if statement in a rock paper scissors game against COM

Tags: python-3.x

I am very much a beginner trying to build a beginner rock paper scissors game. I am having trouble comparing results between the player and the com (random), my if statement is not recognizing the com's move.

```
rock = '''
    _______
---'   ____)
      (_____)
      (_____)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''

``paper = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
          _______)
         _______)
---.__________)
'''

scissors = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
       __________)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''


player = input('What do you choose? Type 0 for Rock, 1 for Paper or 2 for Scissors.\n')

if player == '0':
  print(rock)
elif player == '1':
  print(paper)
elif player == '2':
  print(scissors)

print('Computer chose:')
handsigns = [rock, paper, scissors]

import random
random.shuffle(handsigns)

com = print(handsigns[0])

``if com == 'rock':
  if player == '0':
    print("Draw")
  if player == '1':
    print('You win')
  if player == '2':
    print('You lose')
```

Comment: You are close. Think about comparing a variable to a variable.

Comment: You have some backticks `` in a couple of places in your post, maybe you can edit the post to remove them. ``paper and ``if com ==

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are assigning the return value of the print command to com

```
com = print(handsigns[0])
```

print in this case returns 'None', so that's what com will get assigned.

Try to print the value of com as a debugging step to see the value.

Additionally, handsigns is a list of the 3 display variables you defined above.

```
handsigns = [rock, paper, scissors]
```

Your if statement will never really work out. 'com' will end up being one of the the big docstring values you defined, not the string 'rock'

```
if com == 'rock':
```

Consider using one variable set for logic, and one for display:

```
choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

# get user choice, display a hand symbol for it.

com = random.choice(choices))

# have computer's choice display a hand symbol for it.

# compare user choice and com choice for message about win lose draw.
```